# Phylogenetic Pearson r using phyl.vcv function in “phytools”

Tags: r, correlation, phylogeny

The phyl.vcv function in 'phytools' R package computes a phylogenetic trait variance-covariance matrix between two variables.

Can I use this matrix to compute a phylogenetic Pearson r value? If so, can this r-value be used in a t test (with n-2 df) to test the significance of the correlation?

Comment: You might be better on the mailing list for this topic https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-phylo where specialists in the area may congregate.

Comment: I just posted a solution on my blog here: http://blog.phytools.org/2017/08/pearson-correlation-with-phylogenetic.html.